# Isekai manga where a boy is strong against poison

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I am looking for a fantasy manga where a boy was killed and reincarnated to a fantasy world where he does not have a status of a knight, but his power is strong against poison. He make a star crystal out of a poison rose for his mother and archduke granddaughter. He return with his mother to his father's land and suddenly becomes crown prince.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2):

*[Maseki Gurume: Mamono no Chikara o Tabeta Ore wa Saikyou!](https://mangakakalot.com/read-et0zt158504885923)*

[image: Front cover of *Maseki Gurume: Mamono no Chikara o Tabeta Ore wa Saikyou!*]

> In this world, It's only me who can get stronger by eating Magic Stones! 
> At one point, I received an offer to have a smooth life reincarnation from the Goddess-sama... But the skill I got as a prize is Toxins Decomposition EX. Ugh, what a plain skill! Its so pitiful that even my own family makes fun of me... 
> However, one day I realized that because of this skills effect, I can eat and gain power from Magic Stones! I've also been notified that I'm the prince from a neighboring country!? What awaits me in the castle are days of experimenting with Magic Stones and training, the perfect environment for me to become the strongest man there is... 
> And to top it off, I received the Magic Stone of Dullahan! 
> The story of a boy on the path to become a King while being chased by an assertive fiancee and Female Knights starts here!

Found with a search for `isekai manga poison archduke` which led me to [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Isekai/comments/ej40gh/help_finding_name_of_isekai_mangamanhua_the_kid/).